# Request::createFromGlobals() vs. $this->getRequest()

Tags: symfony

I've seen two ways to get the Request object in a controller:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$request = $this->getRequest();
```

I was wondering what the difference was.  Is one way better than the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are even more ways to inject the Request obj.

The $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); method initializes a new Request Obj.

This is already done by the framework for you. In your FrontController(app.php | app_dev.php) the Request Obj is initialized and gets injected by the handle method into the DependencyInjection Container.

```
...
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
...
```

So it is a better way to fetch the request with the DependencyInjection Component:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html

```
$this->getRequest();
```

The function uses the Container to fetch the current request:

```
public function getRequest()
{
    return $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
}
```

An even better way is to inject the Request into your contoller action
http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/book/controller.html#book-controller-request-argument

```
class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function fooAction(Request $request)
    {
        $request->...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->getRequest()` if you ever want to write unit tests. Otherwise no specific preference in context of PHP.

Comment: If you wanted to write unit tests, I suppose the best would be to inject the request: public function fooActoun(Request $request) {}

Comment: it is also injectable by container, but yes - having it injected through reflection on method call works as well