# Symfony Request parameters: createFromGlobals vs injecting Request

Tags: symfony

There is a project I have been assigned, and in one of the controller actions the `$request` variable is being populated by:

`$request = Request::createFromGlobals();`

Followed by the actual value that is being looked for:

`$token = $request->get("access_token");`

However, while writing a test case for this (which wasn't there before):

```
$client = static::createClient();

$client->request(
    'GET',
    '/validate',
    [
        'access_token' => $responseData['access_token']
    ]
);
```

the `$request->get("access_token")` returns `null`. On the contrary, when I change it to inject Request into the action `validateTokenAction(Request $request)`, it works fine and returns the actual value.

Looking up online ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24375033/482305)) seems like `Request::createFromGlobals` should work in getting the passed parameters. So why doesn't it? Is there a difference between the two approaches?

*P.S. The actual functionality of the application (token validation et al) works fine; this seems to be happening just with the test case.*

Comment: Sometimes even accepted answers are incorrect.  Within the context of a symfony application, I cannot think of any valid reason to use Request::createFromGlobals() outside of app.php.  You can dive into the code to see why your test case is not working.  It is actually worth while to do so if you plan on using the symfony framework long term.